# Can a Mamachari be fitted with an 11 speed 52-36T crankset and FD?

Tags: frames, crankset, bottom-bracket, compatibility, derailleur-front

I would like to upgrade this bike with a better and faster crankset, 52-36T, but I'm confused if my planned setup will be compatible with the bike I have. I have consulted in our local bike shop and they said that a Dura-Ace crank would fit but the FD will have a hard time or impossible fitting considering the top tube design of the bike.

I'm not really sure if he saw my bottom bracket being really old. Might there be any modern bottom bracket to fit it at all?

Edit: Finally found an enlightening link
https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/

[image: Side View]

[image: Bottom View]

Comment: are you going to use a full 11spd setup (cassette, rear mech, shifters) as well?

Comment: 1x is all the rage now and you already have it.

Comment: @Paul H, yeah. I want to speedup in flats but also somehow climb easily on hills. I'm thinking if I could use my 11 speed 52-36T crankset and maybe a 11-36T cassette if possible.

Comment: Even if it's possible, is it really worth fitting a Dura Ace groupset to what looks like a run-around shopping bike? If you want something faster, you could probably buy a whole bike that's better suited to your needs for less than the cost of Dura Ace.

Comment: @DavidRicherby my build is a sleeper bike. Sorry but that frame design is my long time dream since I was a kid. I can afford a modern Road/MTB bike whenever I want but there's this sense of happiness and contentment each time I ride that bike. I want to enjoy cycling. That's why I'm only upgrading parts or  slightly modify the frame to be compatible with modern components. Modern components are easier to find than old/retro once.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW sounds like you'd be better suited with 1x11 MTB drivetrain

Comment: @PaulH will that make the same speed as 52/11 combo?

Comment: Shimano MTB cassettes ranging from 11 - 46 T are readily available. Use whatever chainring you want. (I question the need for 52x11 on this bike)

Comment: @PaulH I'm afraid we are not in the same page here. I mean 52-36T Crankset to 11-42T Cassette. Is it possible without any incompatibility and shifting issues?

Comment: I'm telling you that you don't want to mess with a front derailleur and a double crankset. If you have the resources to a new road or mountain bike whenever you want, you should should stop messing around and get a 1x XT or SLX group and a road/gravel 1x crankset to go with it.

Comment: Given the aerodynamics of such a bike, it will be virtually impossible to get it going fast enough to need a 52T chainring.

Comment: After reading the whole discussion my recommendation would be a power meter crankset. It's not going to make anyone faster, but it could help the OP to figure out why he keeps being passed.

Comment: If you install a FD you will almost certainly have to discard the chain guard.

Comment: I suggest moving this comment thread to the chat room

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After so many days searching the web, asking questions here and asking some local mechanics, I finally got an answer.

My bike can be fitted with modern Threaded Bottom Bracket and Dura-Ace Crankset. Chainstay clearance is ok. I will ditch the chain guard.
As for the FD, if I can't fit it because of the top tube, I will just weld an adapter to it for a braze-on option.

The only problem now is the compatibility of the Dura-Ace road FD with XTR 2x MTB shifter.
Base from this link https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1297/bicycle-front-derailleur-compatibility/, I'm willing to push this experiment for my ultimate sleeper bike.
If it fails, it fails but I will find a way.

Comment: If you can - store the takeoff parts like the chain guard.  Someday you or some future owner may want to revert to stock.

Comment: @Criggie I have no plan of reselling my bike. I will do a complete overhaul of it. I hope I'll finish this project this year.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fit a modern crank you'll need to be able to fit a compatible bottom bracket. Right now you have a threaded bottom bracket shell with a non-cartridge bottom bracket. If the threads are ISO/English standard and the width is standard threaded BB road width (68mm) then you can fit an external bearing road BB and road crank. The BB shell looks a bit wide though.

The other major issue is clearance between the chainstay and large chainrings that the frame was not designed for

Comment: Another issue will be the chainguard that will get in the way of larger and/or double rings and in the case of double rings also with the front derailleur..

Comment: @Carel I'm willing to remove my chain guard. I know it won't accommodate a larger chainring.

Comment: I just measured my BB width. I'm not sure if I'm getting it right but I got 70mm. Maybe it's that 68mm you're saying. Also, plenty of local stores I came to talk with, states that there's a compatible BB and dura-ace crank for my bike. The only problem now is the FD and also a MTB shifter compatible with it.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW I really think you should stick with a 1x MTB drivetrain. Then you don't have any issues with your derailleur and shifter compatibility, and you still get plenty of range (e.g., 46 x 11-46)

Comment: @PaulH I currently have 42T chainring. It's so disapponting whenever some cyclist pass on me even though I'm at my biggest chainring and highest gear. It doesn't mean I want to compete with them but I also want to be faster. It's just to easy for me ripping 42/11 combo..

Comment: There are many chainrings available between 42T and 52T.

Comment: @WashichawbachaW you really need to practice spinning. Even 120rpm at 42/11 gives you 60 km/h and 150rpm shouldn't be out of reach. If you can't hit these speeds, it's probably something else than gears that limits you.

Comment: BTW, 70mm is standard Italian BB width. There are external BB cups for those, too.

Comment: @ojs I think I spin really fast while on my 42T Big Ring and 11T cog. I don't count how much RPM I produce while pedaling but the feel on the pedals are getting really2x soft and fast in flats, like I was just back pedaling. I have tried a 50-34T chainring with a road bike and I found myself settling in the cog next to 11 or the 2nd highest gear while on the biggest 50T chainring. It feels so normal and stable and I know I'm spinning well. I can go all in to 11T highest gear without any worries.

Comment: If you can comfortably 'spin' a 50-12 on a road bike on the flat you should probably just give the bike to your team mechanic to sort out for you.

Comment: If it's a standard 68mm BB I don't see why the shaft can't be replaced with a longer one (longer on the chainring side, that is).  No need to switch to external bearings.

Comment: The OP wants to use current dura ace, which requires either external bearings or one of the new larger BB shells.

Comment: @ojs - But there's no reason why he would need to use a Dura Ace.  2-speed cranks have been around since the Ice Ages.  He *would* have a little difficulty with the derailer, but if he looks around he can probably find one that will fit.

Comment: You might want to look up the difference between need and want.

Comment: I suggest moving this comment thread to the chat room

Answer (score 3):

Alternative answer - if you want more climbing gears, consider a wide-ranging Internally Geared Hub in your wheel.     An 11 speed Shimano Alfine has 500% range, and a 14 speed Rohloff is also enormous.

This will return your bike to a vintage look, and do away with the entire derailleur system.  You'll also be able to keep that chainguard, whereas fitting a front mech will require you to remove it completely, or worse butcher big holes into the metal.

Downside - these hubs are not cheap, and could easily cost more than your bike.  Plus they need building into the middle of your rear wheel, and your bike frame needs some way to tension the chain, so longer dropouts, not modern vertical ones (though you can also use a chain tensioner in the same style as a rear deraileur)

Comment: that's really a good advise but Alfine and other Shimano's commuter series of components are not available in my country. If I order that outside the country, shipping cost will spike up the price compared to what is already available here. I'm ok taking off the chain guard.